# C++2a comparison-based topological sort algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, generics, c++20

Here's my attempt at a C++2a Standard Library–friendly "[topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)" algorithm. There are several areas of interest here:

- The algorithm is comparison-based and in-place, just like `std::sort`. This makes it something like \$\mathcal{O}(n^3)\$, which is certainly worse than it ought to be. Can we speed it up somehow without requiring any extra memory?
- Is my use of `operator<=>`, `partial_ordering`, etc. idiomatic? (Obviously we're still in the process of developing these idioms, but I think it'd be good to start talking about them.)
- I threw in an "optimization" for comparison categories other than `partial_ordering` (namely `strong_ordering` and `weak_ordering`). Is this safe? Is this smart? Is this *sufficiently* smart?

---

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <compare>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

// Some helpers that should be standard but aren't.

template<class It> using iterator_category_t = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category;
template<class It> using iterator_value_type_t = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type;
template<class It> struct is_forward_iterator : std::is_base_of<std::forward_iterator_tag, iterator_category_t<It>> {};
template<class It> inline constexpr bool is_forward_iterator_v = is_forward_iterator<It>::value;
template<class It> struct is_random_access_iterator : std::is_base_of<std::random_access_iterator_tag, iterator_category_t<It>> {};
template<class It> inline constexpr bool is_random_access_iterator_v = is_random_access_iterator<It>::value;
template<class T> struct is_weak_ordering : std::is_convertible<T, std::weak_ordering> {};
template<class T> inline constexpr bool is_weak_ordering_v = is_weak_ordering<T>::value;

// One more helper that WILL be standard but isn't.

template<class T = void>
struct spaceship {
    constexpr auto operator()(const T& a, const T& b) const -> decltype(a <=> b) {
        return a <=> b;
    }
};

template<>
struct spaceship<void> {
    template<class T, class U>
    constexpr auto operator()(T&& t, U&& u) const
        -> decltype(std::forward<T>(t) <=> std::forward<U>(u)) {
        return (std::forward<T>(t) <=> std::forward<U>(u));
    }
    using is_transparent = void;
};

// Here's the topological sorting algorithm itself.

template<class FwdIt, class Comparator = spaceship<iterator_value_type_t<FwdIt>>>
void topological_sort(FwdIt first, FwdIt last, Comparator cmp = Comparator{})
{
    if constexpr (
        is_random_access_iterator_v<FwdIt> &&
        is_weak_ordering_v<decltype(cmp(*first, *first))>
    ) {
        std::sort(first, last, [&](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
            return cmp(a, b) < 0;
        });
    } else {
        for (auto mark = first; mark != last; ++mark) {
            auto current_min = mark;
            auto last_min = current_min;
            while (true) {
                for (auto it = mark; it != last; ++it) {
                    if (cmp(*it, *current_min) < 0) {
                        current_min = it;
                    }
                }
                if (last_min == current_min) break;
                last_min = current_min;
            }
            if (current_min != mark) {
                using std::swap;
                swap(*current_min, *mark);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here's some quick-and-dirty testing code. The `Task` example is cribbed from one of the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230881/stable-topological-sort .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

struct Task {
    char k;
    Task(char k): k(k) {}
    bool operator==(Task rhs) const { return k == rhs.k; }
    bool operator!=(Task rhs) const { return k != rhs.k; }
    bool depends_on(Task rhs) const {
        if (k == 'A' && rhs.k == 'B') return true;
        if (k == 'B' && rhs.k == 'D') return true;
        return false;
    }
    struct order {
        std::partial_ordering operator()(Task a, Task b) const {
            if (a == b) return std::partial_ordering::equivalent;
            if (b.depends_on(a)) return std::partial_ordering::less;
            if (a.depends_on(b)) return std::partial_ordering::greater;
            return std::partial_ordering::unordered;
        }
    };
};

float nan() { return 0./0.; }

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vi {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5};
    topological_sort(vi.begin(), vi.end());
    for (auto&& elt : vi) {
        std::cout << elt << std::endl;
    }

    std::vector<float> vec {3, nan(), 1, 4, 1, 5, nan(), 2, 6, nan()};
    topological_sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    for (auto&& elt : vec) {
        std::cout << elt << std::endl;
    }

    std::list<Task> tasks { 'A','B','C','D','E','F' };
    topological_sort(tasks.begin(), tasks.end(), Task::order{});
    for (auto&& elt : tasks) {
        std::cout << elt.k << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Here's the complete code on Godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/g/pvMpHQ)

Comment: It seems like the DFS approach from the linked wikipedia article could be worked into a general \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ topological sort (well, by using stack space for recursion...). It's really hard to lower the runtime complexity of the task without harder guarantees (like `weak_ordering`) or using additional temporary space.

Comment: Have you looked at Kahn, as described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting ? O(Verts+Edges)

Comment: @PhilH: I've definitely read the Wikipedia page; it doesn't seem interested in comparison-based topological sort algorithms. O(V+E) is great and all, but merely to *compute the value of* E takes O(V^2) comparisons... and you can't store the resulting set anywhere unless you can dig up O(V^2) extra space...

Comment: I will freely admit this isn't my specialism, but it seems... *rare*... to do a topological sort on a graph whose edges you do not know. And in the case of a standard, I would expect O(V+E) on normal use to outweigh O(n^3) on an unusual one. But, I may be completely unclear what you mean, so by all means give an example.

Comment: @PhilH: Well, maybe I don't see what you mean, either. :) How would you implement a `topological_sort` function that passes the three tests in the `main()` routine above? In particular, `tasks` is a "graph on 6 nodes and E edges, where E is initially unknown."

Comment: In that code, the number of edges is known; A->B, B->D, so there are 2 edges. I'm struggling to imagine a scenario where you cannot know whether X & Y have a dependency without comparing them directly. Usually either X knows its children, or Y knows its parents. Have I missed something obvious there?

Comment: @PhilH: Nothing prevents me in the task example from changing the vector to `{' A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', ' D', 'D' }`. It's just another data set, but the edges are completely different - and `topological_sort` needs to cope with that. No child knows all the parents, no parent knows all its children, they just know "that specific instance is a parent/child of mine".if you compare them.

Comment: Then I would say there is no algorithm which can perform a topological sort faster than O(n^3) if it takes O(n^2) to discover the edges of the graph; yet any graph in which the edges are known can be sorted far faster than this. That leaves me where I was before; an algorithm for the usual case (where edges are known) would need to be provided alongside this.

Comment: @PhilH: It could be done in \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ (remember, it's \$\mathcal{O}(\lvert V \rvert + \lvert E \rvert) = \mathcal{O}(n + n^2)\$), but that requires additional space AFAICT (which OP doesn't want), or even faster under certain conditions (see the `std::weak_ordering` optimization for \$\mathcal{O}(n \log n)\$)

Comment: Is there any rationale behind making `spaceship` templated? Your only `void` specialization could do all the job, eh?

Comment: @bipll: "Is there any rationale...?" Just symmetry with the older `std::plus<T>`, `std::equal_to<T>`, etc. If I ran the zoo, the `<T>` versions wouldn't exist and we'd just use the `<>` versions for everything (and they wouldn't need `<>`, and they'd just be global `inline` lambdas, and, and,...) :)

Answer (score 4):

### What's "C++2a-friendly" anyway?

I'm not sure what you mean by C++2a-friendly. The spaceship operator isn't out yet, and will be part of the next standard. So it isn't C++2a-friendly, it's C++2a period, or what don't I understand?

If by C++2a-friendly you mean: using available features from the next standard (e.g concepts in gcc), I believe you can do a bit better than you do. For instance, type traits should be expressed as concepts, and overloads on concepts should allow for algorithm selection.

Here's an example of how it looks like in gcc, with -fconcepts enabled:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template <typename T>
concept bool RandomAccessIterator = requires (T a, T b, std::size_t n) {
    {a - b} -> std::size_t;
    {a < b} -> bool;
    {a[n] } -> typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type&;
    // etc.
};

template <typename Iterator> // unconstrained template argument
bool is_long(Iterator, Iterator) {
    std::cout << "Not a random access Iterator, couldn't compute distance!\n";
    return false;
}

template <RandomAccessIterator Iterator> // Iterator must satisfy the concept
bool is_long(Iterator f, Iterator l) {
    std::cout << "computing distance...\n";
    return std::distance(f, l) < 10 ? false : true;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec(20, 3);
    std::list<int> lst(18,5);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_long(vec.begin(), vec.end()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_long(lst.begin(), lst.end());
}
```

### You can be more expressive

I needed time to understand why `is_weak_ordering_v` is a condition to use `std::sort`, until I got that it truly means that the elements are totally ordered (`strong_ordering` is convertible to `weak_ordering`). It's the kind of little things that affect readability; `is_totally_ordered` would have been better in my opinion.

You can also be more expressive by using standard algorithms. For instance,

```
            // ...
            auto current_min = mark;
            for (auto it = mark; it != last; ++it) {
                if (cmp(*it, *current_min) < 0) {
                    current_min = it;
                }
            }
```

can be expressed as:

```
auto current_min = std::min_element(mark, last, [&cmp](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
    return cmp(a, b) < 0;
});
```

### Can you really make topological sort standard?

I'm skeptical. It means you have to rely on iterators as an abstraction over the set of elements and that, in turn, means: either that the edges are apparent in the elements lay-out (i.e: the range between iterators is already topologically sorted), or that the dependencies are hidden inside the elements, which seems really sub-optimal to me.

Comment: A totally ordered set doesn't allow ties between elements, so that only describes `std::strong_ordering`. `std::weak_ordering` does allow ties, so it is more general, and calling it a "total order" would be wrong (as it isn't). // Re last point: Or the dependencies could (only) be known to the `Comparer`.

Comment: @hoffmale: "total order" might not be the right term; by that I meant that all the elements can be compared one to another. `is_weak_ordering` is generally understood in opposition to `is_strong_ordering`, not `is_partial_ordering`.

Comment: I believe that to the extent C++ has a notion of "total ordering," it does indeed mean "total weak ordering." Whether *ties* between different (i.e. non-substitutable) elements are allowed [i.e. weakness/strongness] is orthogonal to whether *unorderedness* between different elements is allowed [partialness/totalness], but the C++2a Working Draft essentially does not admit the possibility of a "strong partial order," any more than C++03 admitted the possibility of a "bidirectional output iterator." (Also in C++ "strong" is a synonym for what normal people seem to call "strict".)

Comment: Good point on `min_element`. Re "type traits should be expressed as concepts, and overloads on concepts should allow for algorithm selection", I would be delighted to see an example of how that should look in this specific case — naturally, posted as an answer, to reap well-deserved upvotes. :)

Comment: @Quuxplusone: I've added a simplified concept example.

Comment: @papagaga: You've added an example of Concepts *syntax*, which I do already know (more or less). What I meant was, what would your advice that "type traits should be expressed as concepts" actually look like in this specific case? Even if I try to apply your example to my actual program, you *seem* to be recommending to replace my two-line definition of `is_random_access_iterator_v` with something that took you 7 lines counting the `// etc.` comment! That's clearly not what you *meant* with your advice, but, what *did* you mean?

Comment: @Quuxplusone: I indeed think you should replace your two-line definition of a random access iterator by a concept-based definition. Why? 1/ it's more robust: I can base my custom iterator's category on `std::random_access_iterator_tag` without respecting the interface; it will pass your test, not the concept-based test. 2/ it will ship with C++2a, at least as a part of `<range>`, which relies heavily on concepts, so you won't have to write a line when it's out. 3/ overload sets are less prone to errors than `if constexpr` dispatching, where the order of `if` clauses matters.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some C++20'y things you can use to improve your code even further (and some non-C++20'y things).

> Some helpers that should be standard but aren't.

Where's your proposal? :) Just kidding of course.

1. Down with `typename`! Please remove those `typename`s in the first two using declarations, they are unnecessary.
2. <del>What's up with the `decltype(a <=> b)`? Just use `decltype(auto)` as the return type.</del> SFINAE, although as OP said: It might not make sense to be SFINAE-friendly here because the other comparison function objects aren't.
3. With constraints you can split off `topological_sort`:

   ```
   template<class FwdIt, class Comparator = spaceship<iterator_value_type_t<FwdIt>>>
       requires is_random_access_iterator_v<FwdIt> &&
                is_weak_ordering_v<decltype(cmp(*first, *first))>
   void topological_sort(FwdIt first, FwdIt last, Comparator cmp = Comparator{})
   {
       std::sort(first, last, [&](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
           return cmp(a, b) < 0;
       });
   }

   template<class FwdIt, class Comparator = spaceship<iterator_value_type_t<FwdIt>>>
   void topological_sort(FwdIt first, FwdIt last, Comparator cmp = Comparator{})
   {
       for (auto mark = first; mark != last; ++mark) {
           auto current_min = mark;
           auto last_min = current_min;
           while (true) {
               for (auto it = mark; it != last; ++it) {
                   if (cmp(*it, *current_min) < 0) {
                       current_min = it;
                   }
               }
               if (last_min == current_min) break;
               last_min = current_min;
           }
           if (current_min != mark) {
               using std::swap;
               swap(*current_min, *mark);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. As already mentioned, you can use `std::min_element`.
5. Use `std::iter_swap` instead of `using std::swap; swap(/*...*/);`.
6. You can use concepts to simplify your type traits. For example:

   ```
   template<class It>
   concept RandomAccessIterator = std::is_base_of_v<std::random_access_iterator_tag, iterator_category_t<It>>;
   ```
7. You can drop the explicit specialization of `spaceship<void>` by using the same trick as `topological_sort`. You can merge the two call operators into the same class, and then use constraints to the second one better to overload resolution using `requires std::is_same_v<void, T>`.

Comment: "What's up with the `decltype(a <=> b)`?" — SFINAE! Although I'm not sure if we want to care about SFINAE here. `std::plus<T>::operator()` just pretends that `T + T` always returns `T`, but for `T <=> T` I don't think there's any even remotely sane "default" return type. Maybe the non-transparent version of `std::spaceship` really *shouldn't* exist.

Comment: @Quuxplusone Oh yeah, I wasn't even thinking about SFINAE. Yeah, probably.

Comment: Also: I weakly disagree with 1 (I'd rather write `typename` the way I've been doing since C++98, than track down compiler errors related to omitting it when it couldn't be omitted — but I am sure I'll come around eventually); 3 is definitely true but doesn't that make the code *longer* and overload resolution *harder*, compared to `if constexpr`?; 4+5 good points; 6 missing a `_v` but good point; 7 I don't understand quite what you mean here.

Comment: @Quuxplusone Oh wow, you're the first one to actively like `typename` ;) I guess you could argue that it does make the code longer, but I think it reduces the cognitive overhead of analysing the function (you are effectively using two separate algorithms => so two overloads IMO). 6) (oops, nvm, you're right.) 7. Merge the two call operators into same class and use a `requires` on one to make it preferable when `T = void`.